# How can access the remote 'TC' path on an Okuma P control

Tags: okuma

I need to be able to access the 'Remote Path' that is entered by the user in the 'DNC-T Device Setting' Utility program.  Are these paths stored in a ini file or in the registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNC-T Device Setting Utility is an "easy access" approach to modifying registry keys.

The Program (located in `C:\OSP-P\Tools\`)
[image: DNC-T Device Setting Utility]

Not only can you see which locations have been added, but following this pattern you could add / modify / or delete keys as well. They are stored in the registry in the following location:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OKUMA\DNC-T\`

[image: Location]